# how to make Weblogic NodeManager start a Managed Server with a different user

Tags: unix, weblogic, administration

I'm setting up Weblogic on linux.
My Node manager is running as root.
When I use it to start a managed server, I see the managed server's process owner is root.
I would like it to be another username. An unprivileged user.
Is there a way to specify it for Node Manager?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That would not be possible. Even though Java can do many things, on the OS level, its just a process running on a shell, in specific java. Nothing can change that fact. Any new processes/threads/connection pools etc. it creates, they will all be by the user running the java process. Starting a managed server using nodemanager is the same as starting a new process or thread using an existing process and hence that would not be possible. Besides the startup using nodemanager is the same as startup using WLST.

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news.